# getting error on installing `@angular/cli` on mac system

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I am trying to install the `angular5` or later to my mac machine. but getting error(s) how to solve this? here is the error details:

```
03:56:57 {master} ~/arif/ng/mean-angular5$ node -v
v6.11.1
03:57:00 {master} ~/arif/ng/mean-angular5$ clear

03:57:35 {master} ~/arif/ng/mean-angular5$ npm install -g  @angular/cli
npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/jinugeorge/Downloads/node-v6.11.1-darwin-x64/bin/node" "/Users/jinugeorge/Downloads/node-v6.11.1-darwin-x64/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: require-from-string@^1.1.0
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 2.0.2
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'cosmiconfig'
npm ERR! notarget 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jinugeorge/arif/ng/mean-angular5/npm-debug.log
03:58:05 {master} ~/arif/ng/mean-angular5$
```

Comment: @rijin - already done. after I get this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm had an issue over the last few days: 
https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj

Unfortunately, this problem seems to still be an issue for some users.